# How to use children path in Vue.Js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

This code

```
 index.js

{
  path: '/test',
  name: 'test',
  component: Test,
  children: [{
    path: 'p1',
    name: 'p1',
    component: P1
  }]
}
```

in Component Test

```
test.vue

<template>
<div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <button v-on:click="navigateTo('/test/p1')">p1</button>
</div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
      methods: {
         navigateTo(route) {
          this.$router.push(route)
         }
       }
      }
 </script>
```

in Component P1

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>P1</h1>
</div>
</template>
```

**When i click button p1  i has path in browser but not load component p1. why??**
I'm new in vue.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed the `<router-view></router-view>` in your parent template (in `test.vue`). Router view is where the child component gets rendered. i.e.

```
<template>
<div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <button v-on:click="navigateTo('/test/p1')">p1</button>
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: Ok it works But i want it to show only  component P1 when i click  button ,
What should I do?

Comment: Then you may need to move the unwanted template (`<h1>Test</h1>
    <button v-on:click="navigateTo('/test/p1')">p1</button>`) to a default child component. And only have the `<router-view></router-view>` at the parent template. then you router should change to: ```{
  path: '/test',
  name: 'test',
  component: Test,
  children: [{
    path: '',
    name: 'default',
    component: P0
  }, {
    path: 'p1',
    name: 'p1',
    component: P1
  }]
}```